# How to write a SQL query to rank users based on weighted actions and time decay?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

There are **2 actions** (A and B) that I want to use to rank users.

Both actions will "loose" value linearly as the time elapses.

**Action A**: 60% weight

**Action B**: 40% weight

> Score = SUM [ Action Weight * 1000000 / (Current Timestamp - Action Timestamp) ]

### MySQL Table with User's Actions

```
user_id | action | timestamp
1       | A      | 1524428013410
1       | B      | 1525431531237
2       | B      | 1525578131563
```

Users with the highest scores should be in the top of the ranking.

How to write a performant SQL query to compute the users' scores?

The output of the query should be in the format below:

```
user_id | score
1       | 0.92830
2       | 0.76382
```

(The scores in the above example are only placeholders for the output format I need).

Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: How many different actions do you have ? Its always A or B ?

Comment: There are only 2 actions, A and B.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, you just need an ordinary `GROUP BY`. You can `JOIN` the weights. Use `ORDER BY` to sort. Assuming your table is called `action_user`.

```
SELECT au.`user_id`,
       sum(a.`weight` / (current_timestamp() - au.`timestamp`)) `score`
       FROM `action_user` au
            INNER JOIN (SELECT 'A' `action`,
                               .6 `weight`
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'B' `action`,
                               .4 `weight`) a
                       ON a.`action` = au.`action`
       GROUP BY au.`user_id`
       ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Not sure about your formula though. That are some very small numbers. Maybe change that as needed.

Comment: Not sure about the divide.

Comment: That works very well! I updated the formula adding a multiplier of `1000000` to make scores look better. Thanks! @sticky-bit

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
   SELECT
        user_id,
        sum( IF(a.`action` = 'a', 0.6, 0.4) * 1000 / TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, a.timestamp, now()) ),

    FROM actions a

    group by user_id
```

Comment: That's awesome! It worked correctly. +1 for the brevity @user2736880